# HtmlAgilityPack - SelectNodes Intermittently responds with NullPointer exception

Tags: nullpointerexception, html-agility-pack

I am a newbie to HTMLAgilityPack but now gradually able to implement successfully in my program. The problem what i have is "SelectNodes" Intermittently returns Nullpointer exception. But it does work sometimes. I tried to forcibly wait, using the Sleep Command , debug/step in the code , but does not help, sometimes i pass the line but sometimes i fail at that line with error
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Core.dll
Additional information: Value cannot be null."

This the website i am trying to load and read values from the nodes...
https://www.g2crowd.com/categories/mobile-app-testing

Not sure if this is something related to cookies / website page timing out.. i am not able to figure out and i probably overlooked any properties that need to be set for HTMLWeb()

here is my code:

```
HtmlWeb webGet = new HtmlWeb();
var document = webGet.Load("https://www.g2crowd.com/categories/mobile-app-testing");
//THIS BELOW LINE INTERMITTENTLY FAILS, AT TIMES , IT POPULATES THE ARRAY
 HtmlNode[] symbolnodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h5[@class=\"margin-bottom-4th font-weight-bold ellipsis\"]").ToArray();
foreach (HtmlNode item in symbolnodes)
{
}
```

I suspected on cookies , i tried to add this below code , but did not help on that as well

```
                    webGet.PreRequest += request =>
                {
                    request.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
                    return true;
                };
```

Comment: " not sure if my Question is not clear" . Can any HTMLAgilityPack expert or someone help me on this please?

Answer (score 0):

i was able to resolve this. the problem is for each page the HTML nodes are different. I am not sure if this is something related to Dynamic HTML concept, so the element i specified to query returns NULL. I was trying to load 100 different pages 1 by 1, so somewhere somepages has different elements though they all belong to the same website.